# Inputmask widget doesnt work on odoo 10 c

Tags: xml, widget, odoo-10

I am trying using input mask widget on my Odoo 10c.

I have created char fields on my python files, and then I tried to call it on my .xml like this:

```
<field widget="mask" data-inputmask-mask="99/99/9999" name="number" />
```

But the mask does not show up. Why this doesn't work? Please help me, thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like there is something about your folder permissions.

I had similar problems before. Try to change it into 777.

Comment: waw silly me, i forgot about my folder permission
it work like a charm dude! thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Make sure you've done to`sudo chmod -R 777 /your_directory`

Comment: This is what I mean, you should use this line.